# In Xamarin, how do you scale an image without having it take up the same amount of space as it would unscaled?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do you scale an image and not have it take up the full width/height of the unscaled image? In this simple example I want my image to be 25% of the width and height of the container it is in.

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
       <Image
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, .25, .25"
           Source="{Binding NiceImage}" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

That does scale the image but the image still takes up the same amount of space as the unscaled image. `Aspect` doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: Can you post the other xaml that makes up the page?

Comment: Actually, I just wrapped it in a `<StackLayout WidthRequest="100">...` and it worked as expected. But it doesn't work as a percent of the width, which is what I need.

Comment: Grid layout would be the smart thing to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the WidthRequest of the image to that of the parent container, but scaled with a value converter.

If you create a value converter that looks like:

```cs
public class CoefConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double coef = 1.0;

        if (parameter is string)
            coef = double.Parse(parameter as string);

        return (double)value * coef;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can use it in the markup like so:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScaleImage"
             x:Class="ScaleImage.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CoefConverter x:Key="cc" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout x:Name="theStack">

        <Image Source="mountain.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference theStack}, Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource cc}, ConverterParameter=0.25}"  />
        <Label Text="This is some text!" FontSize="Medium" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In essence you're setting the WidthRequest of the Image to that of the parent (named theStack) but multiplied by 0.25.

I posted an example here:

https://github.com/curtisshipley/ScaleImageConverter

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `AbsoluteLayout` with a `Grid` with proportional columns.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="{Binding NiceImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: then please add some context (xaml) or try to clarify your question. When I place this in a <StackLayout> and add a `Label` underneath the grid, it works fine for me

Comment: It works fine for you? Can you post your code please. Because I took the time to mock up your answer and it does not work. code -> https://gist.github.com/smchughinfo/e4368d8aeb964bb68824ff07163e9b2a pic -> https://imgur.com/EEHClEb